# AWS S3 presigned url upload returns 200 but the file is not in the bucket using NodeJS & node-fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url, node-fetch

These are the relevant dependencies in my package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.52.0",
    "@aws-sdk/node-http-handler": "^3.52.0",
    "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "^3.52.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.3.1",
    "http-proxy-agent": "^5.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.7",
    "proxy-agent": "^5.0.0"
  }
```

This is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const _ = require('lodash');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs')

//s3 relevant imports
const { S3Client, PutObjectCommand  } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
const { getSignedUrl } = require("@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner");
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const HttpProxyAgent = require('http-proxy-agent');

let s3 = null
app.listen(port, async () => {
  console.log(`App is listening on port ${port}. Static ${root}`)
  try {
    s3 = new S3Client({
      region: 'ap-southeast-2',
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: accessKey.data.access_key,
        secretAccessKey: accessKey.data.secret_key
      }
    });       
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
});

app.get('/uploadS3Get', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const presignedS3Url = await getSignedUrl(s3, new PutObjectCommand({
      Bucket: 'xyz-unique-bucketname',
      Key: 'test/carlos-test.txt',
    }) );

    const optionsForFetch = {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: fs.readFileSync('carlos-test.txt'),
      agent: new HttpProxyAgent ('http://username:password@proxy.com:8080')
    }

    const respFromUpload = await fetch(presignedS3Url, optionsForFetch).catch( err => {
      console.log("error catch from fetch")
      console.log(err);
      return null;
    });
    console.log("completed so this is the respFrom Upload")
    console.log(respFromUpload)
    console.log("sending the response back now")
    res.status(200).send(respFromUpload);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("general catch error")
    console.log(e)
    res.status(500).send(e);
  }
})
```

I get 200 from node-fetch and this is when it gets printed out:

```
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: PassThrough {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 5,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kTransformState)]: [Object]
    },
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'https://xyz-unique-bucketname.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/test/carlos-test.txt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=omitted%2F20220223%2Fap-southeast-2
%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220223T022913Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Signature=sigommitted&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-length%3Bhost&x-id=PutObject',
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 0
  }
}
```

However, even if the node-fetch PUT using the signed url is returning 200, the file itself is not in the bucket.

What is the wrong with my code and why is AWS SDK misleading by saying 200 response but file is missing?

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion**: use their `createPresignedPost` mechanism rather than the `getSignedUrl` / PutObjectCommand

The server-side code is similar, but offers better features for content-type matching and for conditions like setting a max file size. See [@aws-sdk/s3-presigned-post](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_s3_presigned_post.html)

```js
const { url, fields } = await createPresignedPost(client, postOpts);
```

Here's my WIP typescript code so far for the client upload. The output of `createPresignedPost` gets passed in like `uploadFileAsFormData({ destUrl: url, formFields: fields, targetFile, method: 'POST' })`
Disclaimer: I've made changes since last running it successfully and haven't yet added functional tests so it might be buggy. (Am roughing it out as part of a larger feature and may not get back to this file for another week.)

```js
import { createReadStream } from "fs";
import http from "http";
import { stat } from "fs/promises";
import FormData from "form-data";


const DefaultHighWaterMark = 1024 * 1024;



export interface UploadFileAsFormDataArgs {
  /**
   * File to upload.
   * REMINDER: verify it is in an authorized directory before calling (/tmp or a mounted working-data volume)
   */
  targetFile: string;

  /**
   * Upload destination URL. (Often a presigned url)
   *
   */
  destUrl: string;

  /**
   * Added as both a request header and as a form field (for the nitpicky unpleasant servers that require it.)
   * mime type of file. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types
   *
   * NOTE: if sending to object store using presigned url, this is likely REQUIRED
   */
  contentType?: string;

  /**
   * HTTP request method. Usually POST or PUT
   */
  method?: string;


  extraHeaders?: Record<string, string>;

  skipResponseBody?: boolean;

  formFields: Record<string, string>;

  /**
   * Option to explicitly set buffer size for the stream. Normally, the default is 64kb in newer nodejs versions, while browsers use
   *  closer to 1MB. The default here follows browser-like default: 1024 * 1024.
   */
  highWaterMark?: number;

  // todo: option for AbortController
  // todo: implement progress reporting w/ callback option
}

/**
 * Upload a file similar to a browser using FORM submit.
 * @param args
 */
export async function uploadFileAsFormData(args: UploadFileAsFormDataArgs): Promise<UploadFileResult> {
  const { formFields, highWaterMark, targetFile, destUrl, contentType } = args;

  const form = new FormData();
  Object.entries(formFields).forEach(([ field, value ]) => {
    form.append(field, value);
  });

  if (contentType) {
    form.append('Content-Type', args.contentType); // in case needed... these object store APIs are finicky and pretty shitty about reporting errors (or success).
  }

  const readStream = createReadStream(targetFile, { highWaterMark: highWaterMark || DefaultHighWaterMark });
  const { size } = await stat(targetFile);
  const appendFileOpts: FormData.AppendOptions = {
    knownLength: size,
  };
  if (contentType) {
    appendFileOpts.contentType = contentType;
  }
  form.append('file', readStream, appendFileOpts);

  const uploadStartedAt = Date.now();

  const responseData: { body: string, statusCode?: number, statusMessage?: string, headers?: Record<string, any> } = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    form.submit(destUrl, (err: Error | null, resp: http.IncomingMessage) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        const { statusCode, statusMessage, headers } = resp;
        const buffers = [] as Buffer[];
        resp.on('data', (b: Buffer) => {
          buffers.push(b);
        });
        resp.on('end', () => {
          resolve({
            body: Buffer.concat(buffers).toString(),
            statusCode,
            statusMessage,
            headers,
          });
        });
        resp.on('error', (err) => {
          reject(err);
        });

        resp.resume();
      }
    });
  });

  const { statusCode, statusMessage, body, headers } = responseData || {};
  return {
    sizeBytes: size,
    statusCode,
    statusMessage,
    rawRespBody: body,
    responseHeaders: headers,
    uploadStartedAt,
    uploadFinishedAt: Date.now(),
  }
}

export interface UploadFileResult {
  sizeBytes: number;
  statusCode: number;
  statusMessage?: string;
  rawRespBody?: string;
  responseHeaders?: Record<string, any>;

  uploadStartedAt: number;
  uploadFinishedAt?: number;
}
```

---

Previous answer:

S3 doesn't support chunked transfer encoding so you should add a `Content-Length` header, along the lines of this:

```js
const { stat } = require('fs/promises'); // move up with the others
const { size } = await stat('carlos-test.txt');
const optionsForFetch = {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: fs.readFileSync('carlos-test.txt'),
      headers: { 'Content-Length': size },
      agent: new HttpProxyAgent ('http://username:password@proxy.com:8080')
    }
```

It's a bummer that S3 doesn't support streaming uploads with presigned urls. I'm shopping around now for object stores that do, but so far the pickings are slim. :/

I agree with you about that 200 response--it's misleading. Their response body includes an xml error though: `<Error><Code>NotImplemented</Code><Message>A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented</Message><Header>Transfer-Encoding</Header>...`

Comment: Hi @ferbs, thanks for replying. I tried adding the headers for Content-Length and size (where size was 10 because the file was 10 bytes only) however it still does not upload the file. May I ask how are you able to see the error.code=NotImplemented, because the Response object that I print out doesn't have that message?

Comment: That xml error was only in the response when content-length was missing. It switched to some other malicious response when content-length was present but content-type was missing. I think.. forgot the details--I ended up switching to their `createPresignedPost` mechanism. I'll update with more info.

Comment: Btw, you might not want to change highWaterMark in an express app. I'm using this in a lambda that can more than spare 1mb.